# Red dashed straight line on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

What does this red line mean on Google Maps? I spotted it by accident and it closely highlights this area of cut trees. I wasn't able to find any info online
https://maps.app.goo.gl/uk9eLyVmxvLQnxDr8
[image: a picture of a forest]

Answer (score 2):

## Ski Hill

According to responses to the    r/GoogleMaps Reddit post "[What is this dashed red line on Google Maps?](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/s/fCsftf17zw)", Maps may use the red dashed straight line to indicate a ski lift.

1. Although there was some disagreement in the thread, the users that claimed it was a ski lift seemed informed, or had development experience, and/or (claimed) inside knowledge. Some of the naysayers may have been  confused about what the OP meant by dashed red line. For example,

   > **[Link to response by a Naysayer](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/comments/8gsm9u/comment/iwhiqlb/)**
   > The image they linked shows they **misunderstood** the OP's question, thinking they were referring to a different type of red line:
   > [image: Map showing a dotted red border completely surrounding an area]
2. The dashed line is located in [Wilsonův les](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wilson+forest-park,+616+00+Brno-%C5%BDabov%C5%99esky,+Czechia/@49.2042747,16.5732186,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x47129425133b8ddf:0xa7ff61b64b159802!8m2!3d49.2042747!4d16.5732186!16s%2Fg%2F121vxc6n)  (Wilson forest-park) and a recent [Google Maps review](https://goo.gl/maps/N1d9zeYYEz1VfEaC7) notes that there used to be a ski hill at that location:

   > **[Ales Vanek's Review (2023-11)](https://goo.gl/maps/N1d9zeYYEz1VfEaC7)**
   > Wilsonův les 
   > 616 00 Brno-Žabovřesky, Czechia 
   >  
   >  It's a beautiful place to visit, especially in the autumn as it's very colourful. This forest/park is a popular for locals, especially dog owners. Zigzag routes takes you through 10ha area, very enjoyable though. **In 1970s there used to be even a ski field being based in one area of the hill (where theviewpointt is now)** but locals decided to get rid of that, after all.